# Any theorems on the derivatives of transcendental functions?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, transcendental-functions

I am interested if there are any theorems/conjectures on the rates of change of transcendental functions. More specifically, I want to know that if $f(x)$ is a transcendental function, and $f(a)\in \Bbb Q$, if $f'(a)$ is transcendental. I know that there are exceptions such as $\exp'(0)=1$ and $\ln(x)$ but I am wondering if these are just [exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_function#Exceptional_set).

Comment: Probably not anything beyond very specific theorems about specific transcendental functions. This is because if $f(x)$ is a transcendental function, then so will be $af(bx)$ for any nonzero real numbers $a$ and $b,$ and so whatever result you might be above to come up with can probably be disproved by choosing $a$ and $b$ appropriately even for $f(x) = e^x.$ For the most part, transcendental functions and transcendental numbers are not all that related to each other.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I see, I ask because I want to know whether the derivative of the Gamma Function at the positive integers is transcendental or not.

Comment: @aleden As $\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$ then many people would like to know that.